# Using Android Studio for Game Programming

Tags: android

I am been working on Android Studio from 6 months and have made few normal and 2-D Game Apps.I want to learn and develop Android Game Programming like Mario , which involve graphics. I read that other than Android SDK (Android Studio) and Java(Eclipse), C#(Visual Studio)  provide more API for gaming. I don't want to struggle for finding game APIS.

My question is should I use Android Studio for game programming. Will be tough/cumbersome to get the API ? Are there any third party API? What will be the difficulty level? I am done googling every little thing, want some concrete reading material.

PS-I have JAVA Experience but newbie in C#.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you to use unity 3d to develop 2d, 3d games on android plateforme. [Official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Qualid,                                                                                                               Ed George I have edited the question